# How to build Event Hub output to Java Functions and capture message to Storage?

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have Service Bus Triggered Java Functions which have Event Hub output.
I would like to capture Event Hub message and store to Storage.
I do not get error, but I don't get service bus message content to store to storage.

1) Is there something wrong how I pass Service Bus message to Event Hub?
2) Is there something I have not noticed in Event Hub capture?

Avro file: (I was expecting that I get Service Bus message content, but got some config data to storage)

Objavro.codecnullavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"EventData","namespace":"Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging","fields":[{"name":"SequenceNumber","type":"long"},{"name":"Offset","type":"string"},{"name":"EnqueuedTimeUtc","type":"string"},{"name":"SystemProperties","type":{"type":"map","values":["long","double","string","bytes"]}},{"name":"Properties","type":{"type":"map","values":["long","double","string","bytes","null"]}},{"name":"Body","type":["null","bytes"]}]}

CODE:
    package com.topictriggereventhuboutput;

```
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with Service Topic Trigger.
 */
public class TopicTriggerEventHubOutput {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the Service Bus Topic.
     */
    @FunctionName("TopicTriggerEventHubOutput")
    public void run(
    @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
        name = "message",
        topicName = "MyTopic",
        subscriptionName = "MyTopicEHDataLakeSubscription",
        connection = "sbconnstring"
    )
    String message,
    @EventHubOutput(name = "event", 
                    eventHubName = "ingestdatalakeventhub", 
                    connection = "eh2connstring"
    )
    OutputBinding<String> outputItem,
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info(" Topic Trigger EH Output Java Service Bus Topic trigger function executed.");
    context.getLogger().info("Topic Trigger EH message content: "+ message); // This shows correctly!

    // Write the SB Message to the Output binding. 
    outputItem.setValue(message); 

}
```

}

Comment: If you are seeing just the headers in the avro file, that means there was no events received during that avro interval. Is your function triggered? First make sure it can read from the SB topic.

Comment: Function debug clearly indicated that Function got triggered and its getLogger shows correctly that real data is stored in String message. Avro file header proves that source of content originates from service bus thus pipeline is basically working end to end. Question is where is the message content?

Comment: Check incoming messages on the Event Hubs dashboard and make sure it ingested events. If there is incoming messages then you should see them in the avro.